# Zend Framework - tinyMCE - plugin folders are mistaken to be controllers? Help

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, url-rewriting, tinymce

Hi guys I'm trying to integrate the tinymce plugin however I'm running into problems such that almost every feature which requires a plugin to be rendered i.e the add url popup or add image pop up - it opens an empty pop up window. Even if I try to open it inline I get the same blank popup window.. I noticed that whenever I click on lets say url button in tinymCE it opens with reference to my localhost and because of that I'm assuming my application is mistaking the containing javascript folder to be some controller or action.

How can I fix this please - I've set up mod rewrite to allow clean urls as well as ignore the javascript folder but this is a different issue altogether :(

what should I be looking at here.. I can't notice any error sin firebug..

Comment: What are the URLs tinyMCE is trying to load? Are they valid folders? Maybe you could give us a directory structure and the URLs being referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OUCH sorry - I figured it out ... apparently I had set up my htaccess file to ignore file extensions of images but the templates loaded had a file extension of .htm... just added the new extensions to the htaccess and got it fixed.. sorry for panicking  thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting .htaccess with following contents into your MCE directory:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```